# Cannot determine who calls lock_wait

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, profiling, perf

I have a multi-thread application. I can set number of threads to run on (simple data parallelism). When a try to run it with more then 4 threads I see significant drop in performance. Profiler shows a lot of time consumed in `__lll_unlock_wake` and `__lll_lock_wait`, called by `_L_unlock_532` and `_L_lock_926` respectively. I suspect locks on heap operations because every thread allocates and frees a lot of data.

The problem is, that any tested profiler (perf, google's pperf) does not show caller above `_L_lock_926` so I cannot check with of my function is causing this locks. I want to use some memory pooling technique to decrease number of heap operations, but I don't want to do it on every data collection. Is there any way to increase depth of call-stack for this function?

anticipating suggestions:

- I've compiled code with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer'
- google's tcmalloc doesn't seem to help
- I cannot use `fork()` because my app needs to run on windows too

Comment: Yes - either ask the linker to set the default stack allocation to a larger value, or explicitly create your threads with a larger stack.

Comment: "*any tested profiler*" There are others: `gprof`, `callgrind`, `oprofile` to just name a few.

Comment: `callgrind` show only user-space code for me, `perf` and `perf -g dwarf` shows the same information so I don't think this is a profilers fault

Comment: Did you compile with debug information and use `perf` with call-graph recording?

Comment: @EOF - yes, i run it with `perf record -g my_app`

Comment: @entro Are you also using the right mode for `perf report -g`?

Comment: @EOF, yes, I try various options, including `perf report -g`

Comment: @entro `perf report -g` allows additional selection of modes for the graph representation: `flat/graph/fractal/caller/callee/function/address`. Have a look at `man perf report`.